# Pascal's triangle curiosity

Tags: number-theory, binomial-coefficients

I noticed the following pattern in the rows of Pascal's triangle:

$$
1 = 11^0\\
11 = 11^1\\
121= 11^2\\
1331= 11^3\\
14641=11^4
$$

at this point I thought maybe this pattern would follow indefinitely, but the next row is
$15101051=7\times2157293$. The next two rows aren't powers of 11 either, they are $1615201561=43\times 37562827$ and $172135352171=29\times5935701799$. Are the first 5 rows the only rows in the Pascal triangle that are powers of 11?
The following row 18285670562881 is a prime (at least according to Linux factor function).
How often primes appear in these rows?
This might be fun to show or investigate. I am just curious.

I just wrote a Python script to generate a few more rows of the Pascal triangle. Each row was also factored up to row n=19:

```
from scipy.special import binom
from sympy import factorint

for n in range(5, 20):
  row = ''
  print('n=%d' % n)
  for k in range(n+1):
    binom_nk = int(binom(n, k))
    row = row+str(binom_nk)
  print(row)
  row_number = int(row)
  factors=factorint(row_number)
  print(factors)
```

n=5
15101051
{7: 1, 2157293: 1}

n=6
1615201561
{43: 1, 37562827: 1}

n=7
172135352171
{29: 1, 5935701799: 1}

n=8
18285670562881
{18285670562881: 1}

n=9
193684126126843691
{5647: 1, 34298587945253: 1}

n=10
1104512021025221012045101
{13: 1, 197: 1, 4649: 1, 92768668286052709: 1}

n=11
1115516533046246233016555111
{11: 1, 101410593913295112092414101: 1}

n=12
1126622049579292479249522066121
{523: 1, 4637: 1, 464557485113006356820471: 1}

n=13
11378286715128717161716128771528678131
{369268429: 1, 180642383: 1, 170574866715037030033: 1}

n=14
11491364100120023003343230032002100136491141
{41: 1, 86399681: 1, 3910184543: 1, 829618322366629399154147: 1}

n=15
11510545513653003500564356435500530031365455105151
{17: 1, 113: 1, 149: 1, 337: 1, 5362678549: 1, 3533441: 1, 2118359: 1, 2972851397279413777: 1}

n=16
116120560182043688008114401287011440800843681820560120161
{7: 1, 13: 1, 10567: 1, 835035230611: 1, 144614294599341081090704192088907914583: 1}

n=17
1171366802380618812376194482431024310194481237661882380680136171
{71: 1, 89: 1, 1583: 1, 11969: 1, 82361: 1, 8401361: 1, 6505783: 1, 2173376383488959250244793817754469: 1}

n=18
118153816306085681856431824437584862043758318241856485683060816153181
{31: 1, 59: 1, 4421: 1, 28979: 1, 248303053: 1, 2030710802068204317879252665132300005649014383107: 1}

n=19
1191719693876116282713250388755829237892378755825038827132116283876969171191
{4506133: 1, 37569563: 1, 70854794496642568411: 1, 99349280033387580503673432191635187608339: 1}

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This happens because:

$$11^{n} = (10 + 1)^{n} = 10^{n} + \binom{n}{1}10^{n-1}+\binom{n}{2}10^{n-2} + \dots + \binom{n}{n-1}10^{1} + 10^{0}$$

By binomial expansion. The pattern first breaks down at $n=5$ because it is the first time one of the binomial coefficients is at least $10$. If you used a higher base (say, hexadecimal), the pattern would continue for longer.

You have associated it with Pascal's Triangle because each row of Pascal's Triangle contains the respective binomial coefficients.

Answer (score 1):

$11^5 = 161051$ but you can get this by using the 1 from the 10s as a carry figure on your 15101051 and the pattern will still work

Answer (score 1):

I found this [Magic 11's](http://jwilson.coe.uga.edu/EMAT6680Su12/Berryman/6690/BerrymanK-Pascals/BerrymanK-Pascals.html#:%7E:text=Each%20row%20represent%20the%20numbers,4%20is%20equal%20to%2014%2C641.)

This even works until the 7th row